# Javascript function paramenters

Tags: javascript

I am confused on a task I have been given:

Function: takes 2 parameters, a string and a label id and writes the string value to the text of the label

• Example:

```
changeLabel('mylabel1', ‘label1’);
```

should change the text value of

```
‘<label id="label1">Form Label1</label>’
```

to

```
‘<label id="label1">mylabel1</label>’
```

I am not sure where to put the variables which need to be passed in, here is my code but it will not validate when it is tested.

```
function changeLabel('mylabel1', 'label1'){
    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = mylabel1;
}

changeLabel('mylabel1', 'label1');
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Function parameters are variables (not string literals).  Have you ever written any JS code before?

Comment: If you are not familiar with functions, read a tutorial first: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html. This will provide much more information than one could provide in an answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: *it will not validate when tested*. Do you mean that it results in a syntax error? In that case, the error will report a line number where the error occurred. It probably will give an error such as "SyntaxError; unexpected string" on the line containing `function`. You can then ask yourself: why is a string unexpected here? if you then open the JS manual and review the syntax for function definitions, you will see that parameters cannot be strings--whatever that would mean. You should then be able to proceed to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define function with `strings` as `parameters`. you should do it like this:

```
function changeLabel(text, id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}

changeLabel('mylabel1', 'label1');
```